# Send large data to ios application through asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, ios, web-services

I want to send large amount of data(a table with thousands of rows) to my fellow ios developer(working on xcode) through asp.net web service.

I am using visual studio 2005 and sql server 2000.

I tried sending DataSet to him but he said he cant use datasets in ios.

Please help which approach should i choose?

Regards,
Abdullah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting the approaches i should use. I went for JSON. it was quite easy to create webservice that returns data in that format.
This link provided me exactly what i wanted.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/jsonwebservice.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Send it as XML or JSON, so its easy for him to parse it. TSV or CSV can be parsed by hand too.
For mobile phones since JSON is lightweight and easy to consume.

Comment: i tried using the getxml() function. It generates the xml of dataset. But by this approach the ios developer has to extract data manually from each tag.
I havent worked with json before, will using json solve this problem plus is Json easily manipulable on ios side?

Comment: Both XML and JSON are easy to parse. JSON parsers is fairly easy to use. Starting iOS5 Apple has made their private NSJSONSerialization class public or use third party parsers like JSONKit, SBJSON

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good resource for what you are trying to do using JSON:

[DataTable JSON Serialization in JSON.NET and JavaScriptSerializer](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer)